# Setting Highcharts maximum Y value to an exact amount without rounding

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Every time I set my min and max values in Highcharts, I never get graphs with the exact min and max that I sent, but always something somewhat close. It seems as though Highcharts is picking a interval range for the axes and if my maximum doesn't conform to the right interval, it gets ignored or rounded off.

For example, if I set a min of 0 and a max of 3125 for a Y axis, I get a Y axis starting with 0 then going up in increments of 500 to a maximum of 3500, which is not at all what I want.

Can I get the chart to use an exact maximum or will it always round up in some wierd way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do.

1) set your tickInterval to a number that divides evenly into your max

2) set 'endOnTick' to false for your y axis, and set your maxPadding to 0.  This will set the chart max to your specification, regardless of where the last tick falls.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.endOnTick

Comment: Will this work if I am running multiple Y Axes? If so, what's the proper way to use option #2, because it's not working at the moment for me.

Comment: And here's one with optional tickPositions property set in order to add an axis label for the end: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/TfvGp/3/

Comment: and just for good measure, one that uses option 1) above as well: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/TfvGp/4/

Comment: i found out tickInterval will be max/32 for guage visualization specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Set the [endOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.endOnTick) property to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner or set min/max values with tickInterval as jlbriggs introdued.

Answer (score 0):

As *jlbriggs* said,

**Highcharts.Options**

```
.....
yAxis: {
  lineWidth: 1,
  maxPadding: 0,
  endOnTick: false,
  labels: {
    formatter: (value) => {
      if(value.isLast !== true) {
        const label_value = Math.ceil((Math.floor(value.value)) / 100) * 100; // round in between numbers to hundreds.
        return this.yAxisLabelFormatting(label_value);
      } 
      return this.yAxisLabelFormatting(value.value); // Maximum number of Y axis, you can do your code logic here.
    }
  }
}
...
```

**Inside Dynamic code:**

```
const interval = (this.axisYmax / 8); // Here I'm using 8, you can use any number as your requirement.
(<Highcharts.AxisOptions>this.highChartOptions.yAxis)['tickInterval'] = interval;
```

Happy coding. :)