# min and max axis value not respected in HighCharts chart with a logarithmic axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, logarithm

I have the a stacked column chart with a logarithmic scaled y axis (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99w72efv/2/), adapted from a basic demo chart)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        yAxis: {
                type:'logarithmic',
            min: 0.3, // I WANT THE Y-AXIS TO START AT 0.3
            min: 25, // I WANT THE Y-AXIS TO END AT 25
            endOfTick:false,
            maxPadding:0,
                    tickInterval:0.1,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

I worked on all the options suggested on this Stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799837/setting-highcharts-maximum-y-value-to-an-exact-amount-without-rounding) to set the exact minimum and maximum y-axis values but without success. 
What can I do to force the y-axis chart to start and end at the values I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the question you found, use Sebastian's answer, with `tickPositioner`. In fact, extremes are proper when setting `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` to false, just labels are not rendered. In that case use `tickPositioner`, for example:

```
  tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
    var ticks = this.tickPositions;

    ticks = $(ticks).filter(function(i, tick) {
      return tick > min && tick < max;
    });

    ticks.slice(0, 0, min);
    ticks.push(max);

    return ticks;

  }
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99w72efv/5/

Answer (score 0):

There is no property `endOfTick` -> you're looking for `endOnTick`

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/99w72efv/4/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.endOnTick

Comment: Forgive my mistake. But the problem is still here: y-axis scale doesn't start at 0.3 and doesn't end at 25.

Comment: Yes it does. If you want the axis ticks to reflect those numbers, you need to user the tickPostions property or the tickPositioner function.