# How can I force Highcharts to respect yAxis.max?

Tags: highcharts

I've noticed that if I specify `yAxis.max` in a Highcharts call:

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    //snip...
    yAxis: {
      max: 30000,
      minorGridLineWidth: 1,
      minorTickInterval: 10000,
      title: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    //snip...
  });
```

The resulting chart will cap the yAxis range at 30000:

[image: The resulting chart will cap the yAxis range at 30000]

**However**, if I specify a somewhat short `height` on the chart's target container:

```
<div id="container" style="height:126px; width:420px;"></div>
```

The resulting chart will not "honor" the yAxis max property:

[image: Highcharts will not honor the yAxis.max property when a height is specified on the chart's target container]

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/kpf2b3Lf/ for an example.

**How can I force Highcharts to respect `yAxis.max` when I specify a short height?**

Comment: Set `endOnTick` to false: https://jsfiddle.net/kpf2b3Lf/2/ In case you want last tick anyway, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368207/min-and-max-axis-value-not-respected-in-highcharts-chart-with-a-logarithmic-axis/35408615#35408615).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually select a `tickInterval` to force highcharts to respect the axis max. This should work if the size of your container is constant.

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kpf2b3Lf/1/

```
yAxis: {
  max: 30000,
  minorGridLineWidth: 1,
  minorTickInterval: 10000,
  tickInterval: 10000,
  title: {
    enabled: false
  }
},
```